# convert video files in grails or java

Tags: java, grails, video

I am trying to find out how to convert video files from mov to mp4 and or ogg.
This is so a mobile app can upload a video to my web-app which is made in grails.
has anyone done this or know how to do it.

any ideas?

Comment: You might find this link helpful
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2768672/how-to-make-convert-operation-from-mov-to-3gp-in-java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would drop down to a native process (in Java it would involve starting a Process, [Apace Commons Exec](http://commons.apache.org/exec/) is an excellent library to manage this) and then run [mencoder](http://www.mplayerhq.hu/DOCS/HTML/en/mencoder.html) (part of the [MPlayer](http://www.mplayerhq.hu) project) or some other native application to convert. A pure Java or Grails approach probably can't touch the wide format support of mencoder (which has [binaries](http://www.mplayerhq.hu/design7/dload.html) for a wide array of operating systems). I do something like this for audio and it scales rather well. I have a servlet that takes uploaded data and saves it to [Amazon S3](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/), then I add a message to [Amazon SQS](http://aws.amazon.com/sqs/) which is read by a java application running on the server. When it detects a new message in the que it downloads the uploaded song, passes it to oggenc2 and lame and then the Java application reads in the output (assuming the processes didn't return any errors) and uploads it back to S3.  If encoding ever slows down too much I can spin up another encoder and point it at the message que. Amazon makes sure that two or more clients arnt given the same Mesage in a close proximity